# Laravel Where Search Query

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Spaces and an Interests table.

I am currently able to get a list of the Space Id's saved as $spaceList but I want my $query variable to retrieve a list of interests that the space_id foreign key matches one of the space_id's from my $spaceList variable.

```
public function index() {

        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);

        $spaceList = Space::where('user_id', $user_id)->pluck('space_id')->toArray();
        $query = Interest::where('space_id', $spaceList);

        $interests = $query->get(); 

        return view('dashboard')->with('space', $user->space)->with('interest', $interests);
}
```

Thanks, I've been at this for ages now.

Comment: With a proper relation, you could just do `$interests = Space::where('user_id', $user_id)->interests()->get()`

Comment: You  need Proper relations on model or If You share the table structure i will give you the query with joins

Answer (score 0):

you should use `whereIn` instead of `where`

```
$spaceList = Space::where('user_id', $user_id)->pluck('space_id')->toArray();
$query = Interest::whereIn('space_id', $spaceList);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel Eloquent, this is what the [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)  working on

You won't need the $spaceList variable here if it's not used in other places

```
$query = Interest::whereHas('spaces', function($query) use ($user_id) {
    $query->where('user_id', '=', $user_id);
});
```

Please notice, to get this work, you'll need to declare the *spaces* one-to-many relation in the Interest Module

Should be something like this, more details see document [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Interest extends Model
{
    public function spaces()
    {
        // space_id is the column name in your space database table
        // id the the foreign-key target, generally is the primary-key of space table
        return $this->hasMany('App\Space', 'space_id', 'id');
    }
}
```